# Phonegap permissions

Tags: android, cordova, permissions

I am in a situation where I need to read the users contacts. I am able to this but the app asks the user for the contacts permission when it is being installed. I would like to know is there a way by which the user will not be asked for the contacts permission during installation and only when the user is accessing a particular functionality a popup will appear asking for additional permission.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. The app will always ask/show permissions needed while installing.

[Android Permissions](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html#Permissions)

[Security Tips](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html)